# What will be the url for webhook in camunda self managed for local environment?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I have added a web hook from desktop moduler for start event. What will be url for it in camunda self managed local environment

Read the documentation. But didn't find any reference for base url

Answer (score 0):

URLs of the exposed HTTP Webhooks follow this pattern:

`http(s)://<base URL>/inbound/<webhook ID>>`

More can be found here ->
https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/connectors/out-of-the-box-connectors/http-webhook/

Comment: One more info, if you use camunda platform docker image, check in which port the connector is serving. So for my local setup, the webhook url is - `http://localhost:8085/inbound/<webhhok ID>`